# A few questions on prototyping NEAT in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, neural-network, genetic-algorithm, recurrent-neural-network, evolutionary-algorithm

I've recently read the original [paper](http://nn.cs.utexas.edu/downloads/papers/stanley.ec02.pdf) about NeuroEvolution
of Augmenting Topologies by Kenneth O. Stanley and am now trying to prototype it myself in JavaScript. I stumbled across a few questions I can't answer.

---

### My questions:

1. What is the definition of "structural innovation", and how do I store these so I can check if an innovation has already happened before?

   > However,
   >   by keeping a list of the innovations that occurred in the current generation, it
   >   is possible to ensure that when the same structure arises more than once through independent
   >   mutations in the same generation, each identical mutation is assigned the
   >   same innovation number
2. Is there a reason for storing the type of a node (input, hidden, output)?
3. In the original paper, only connections have an innovation number, but in [other sources](http://www.automatonsadrift.com/neat/), nodes do as well. Is this necessary for crossover? (This has already been asked [here.](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/5496/neat-innovation-for-connection-genes-only))
4. How could I limit the mutation functions to not add recurrent connections?

I think that's it for now. All help is appreciated.

---

### The relevant parts of my code:

#### Genome

```
class Genome {
    constructor(inputs, outputs) {
        this.inputs = inputs;
        this.outputs = outputs;
        this.nodes = [];
        this.connections = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < inputs + outputs; i++) {
            this.nodes.push(new Node());
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < inputs; i++) {
            for (let o = 0; o < outputs; o++) {
                let c = new Connection(this.nodes[i], this.nodes[inputs + o], outputs * i + o);
                this.connections.push(c);
            }
        }
        innovation = inputs * outputs;
    }
    weightMutatePerturb() {
        let w = this.connections[Math.floor(random(this.connections.length))].weight;
        w += random(-0.5, 0.5);
    }
    weightMutateCreate() {
        this.connections[Math.floor(random(this.connections.length))].weight = random(-2, 2);
    }
    connectionMutate() {
        let i = this.nodes[Math.floor(random(this.nodes.length))];
        let o = this.nodes[Math.floor(random(this.inputs, this.nodes.length))];
        let c = Connection.exists(this.connections, i, o);
        if (c) {
            c.enabled = true;
        } else {
            this.connections.push(new Connection(i, o, innovation));
            innovation++;
        }
    }
    nodeMutate() {
        let oldCon = this.connections[Math.floor(Math.random(this.connections.length))];
        oldCon.enabled = false;
        let newNode = new Node();
        this.nodes.push(newNode);
        this.connections.push(new Connection(oldCon.input, newNode, innovation, 1));
        innovation++;
        this.connections.push(new Connection(newNode, oldCon.output, innovation, oldCon.weight));
        innovation++;
    }
}
```

#### Node

```
class Node {
    constructor() {
        this.value = 0;
        this.previousValue = 0;
    }
}
```

#### Connection

```
class Connection {
    constructor(input, output, innov, weight) {
        this.input = input;
        this.output = output;
        this.innov = innov;
        this.weight = weight ? weight : random(-2, 2);
        this.enabled = true;
    }
    static exists(connections, i, o) {
        for (let c = 0; c < connections.length; c++) {
            if (connections[c].input === i && connections[c].output === o) {
                return connections[c];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

All answers an sources are welcome. (You are an awesome person!)

Comment: Is there a clear definition of the difference between mutation and crossover?

Comment: A mutation is a change to a single genome by random chance (like adding a node), and crossover means combining two genomes based on their fitness, without any randomness.

Comment: Ok so based on that, doesn't the NEAT paper do Crossover?

Comment: Yes, it does, but that part of the code wasn‘t relevant for my question.

Comment: Well, in 3 you ask "in other sources, nodes [have an innovation number]. Is this necessary for crossover?" and so I think it is relevant

Comment: Also, for 4, you say "How could I limit the mutation functions to not add backpropagation connections?" Do you mean, there are certain architectures you want to avoid? Because, backprop is a method for determining weights. This paper uses an alternative method of computing weights, so backprop isn't happening. Are you saying that there are connections associated with the backprop algo that you want to avoid?

Comment: In question 4 I meant to say recurrent. I fixed that now.

Comment: hmmm... doesn't that require either the mutation function or the fitness function to understand the network topology? Isn't the insight of this paper explicitly not doing that?

Comment: Can I ask what the goal is in penalizing recurrent connections?

Comment: I cant find it anywhere right now, but i read somewhere that if you want to test NEAT on the xor example, you have to disable recurrent connections because else it's possible to find a solution without a single hidden neuron.

Comment: Ok, see my answer. I edited it to include what you've said in the comments, and from reading the paper again, and from looking at a Python implementation https://neat-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/neat_overview.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would very strongly advice against implementing NEAT yourself. If you take a look at the (many) available implementations, it is quite a large project!

1. A structural innovation is any new node or connection that is added to a genome and that has not been seen before. Imagine you have input nodes 1, 2, 3 and output nodes 4, 5. If only connection 2-4 is available, introducing connection 3-4 would be an structural innovation. To check for novelty you need to store all seen structures (i.e., a list of all connections and nodes) with a unique ID for each (this is the core idea behind NEAT, actually!). In our example, connection 2-4 may take ID=1, and connection 3-4 would take ID=2. You can see the connection is new in that no other connection in the list connects 2 and 4. Nodes are normally introduced by creating "a stop" in a connection and simply take the next available ID. For example, connection 2-4 would be deleted and you would have connections 2-5 and 5-4, where node ID=5 is created in the process (as well as two new connections). Note the IDs for nodes and connections may be independent (that is: if you use IDs for connections at all).
2. I'm struggling to think of a **hard** requirement for this. In principle you could simply store nodes in fixed order (input first, output next, then hidden) and then guess their type given their index, which is how you normally do it anyway for performance reasons (imagine trying to remove a node, you would only want to select a hidden node, so you would restrict search to those indices). Some tasks may be more efficient having that info, though, for example checking for recurrent connections (see 4).
3. IDs are useful in crossover, as they allow to quickly know which elements are common between two genomes. Whether to have IDs for nodes as well as connections is an open implementation decision. No IDs for connections makes simpler code (connections are identified by the IDs of the nodes they connect). But you lose the ability to tell apart two connections that connect the same nodes. There is an argument that says that a connection between two given nodes does not necessarily mean the same at different times in evolution (see how your quote mentions "in the same generation"). This is probably not a relevant factor, though! As I said, the convenience for IDs for both nodes and connections is still debated in the NEAT community.
4. In many cases you do not want to allow recurrent connections. The standard way to do this is to check for recurrence every time you try to add a connection. This is a costly step, yes!

If you have more doubts, I recommend you take a look at [this implementation](https://github.com/colgreen/sharpneat) by Colin Green for reference. If he is not the person who knows more about NEAT implementation, he comes close.

Comment: In your first point you said that, when a new node is created old connection is deleted. But in the neat paper an image shows that the connection is disabled.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about current implementation details (particularly the C# implementation). When a new node is added, the connection is destroyed and two new ones are created. You could create an equivalent implementation where a node is "disabled" instead of "destroyed".

Answer (score 0):

This is not the average JS question! Thanks for the links, it's a really interesting paper. I can't claim to be an expert, I have only done toy GA problems, but I did read this paper and related ones. Here is what I understand:

1. I think all you need to worry about is whether a parent, by mutation, produces the same novel gene more than once in a generation. That is, two children, whose gene with the newest innovation number are identical. You can cull those right away. I think they say that it is possible for the same gene to appear in two species at the same time, and they basically say that's fine, that's rare enough not to worry about.
2. I can find at least one reason: "In NEAT, a bias is a node that can connect to any node other than inputs."
3. I believe your question is "must nodes have an innovation number to do crossover?" The answer is no. In the original paper (e.g. Figure 4) they show crossover implemented in a way where only connections have innovation numbers.
4. If you want to change the mutation function to be architecture aware, rather than avoiding recurrent structure, you might want to explicitly add structures you do want. Suppose you want to avoid recurrent connections because you are evolving an image classifier, and you know that convolutions are more suited to the task. In this case, you want your mutation function to be able to add/remove *layers* (and the needed connections). This was [explored in detail last year](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.01041.pdf) by Google Brain:

> Some of the mutations acting on this DNA are reminiscent of NEAT. However, instead of single nodes, one mutation can insert whole layers—i.e. tens to hundreds of nodes at a time. We also allow for these layers to be removed, so that the evolutionary process can simplify an architecture in addition to complexifying it.

Based on your comment about your motivation for question 4, I think you are mistaken. In the XOR example in the original paper, figure 5, they show a starting phenotype that involves no hidden layer. This starting phenotype is not a solution to the XOR problem, but it provides a good starting point: "NEAT is very consistent in finding a solution. It did not fail once in 100 simulations." That is without any penalization for recurrence.